# Select Max value For Each Entity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In Microsoft SQL Server, I have a table with columns EmployeeID, Category and Amount. How can I show just the Category with the highest Amount for each Employee?

Data Example:

```
EmployeeID   Category    Amount
11111        Vacation    4
11111        Personal    2
11111        Holiday     3
22222        Vacation    1
22222        Personal    3
22222        Holiday     2
33333        Personal    5
33333        Holiday     1
33333        Vacation    3
33333        Unspecified 3
```

Results:

```
EmployeeID   Category   Amount
11111        Vacation   4
22222        Personal   3
33333        Personal   5
```

Comment: so you want rows per employee, per category right? I ask because your result does not include `11111` with Category `Personal`

Comment: Why do you so rarely accept an answer?

Comment: Jaya, just the one Category per Employee that has the highest amount

Comment: Probably just forget to click it sometimes scsimon

Answer (score 2):

Another option is the **WITH TIES** clause

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 with Ties *
 From  YourTable
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By EmployeeID Order By Amount Desc)
```

**Returns**

[image]

---

Or using Row_Number() and a CTE

```
;with cte as (
Select *
      ,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By EmployeeID Order By Amount Desc)
 From  YourTable
)
Select EmployeeID
      ,Category
      ,Amount
 From cte where RN=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few different options. Any of them can perform better than the other depending available indexes, so all three are worth testing in your environment.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL,
    Category VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Amount MONEY NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData (EmployeeID, Category, Amount) VALUES
    (11111, 'Vacation   ', 4),
    (11111, 'Personal   ', 2),
    (11111, 'Holiday    ', 3),
    (22222, 'Vacation   ', 1),
    (22222, 'Personal   ', 3),
    (22222, 'Holiday    ', 2),
    (33333, 'Personal   ', 5),
    (33333, 'Holiday    ', 1),
    (33333, 'Vacation   ', 3),
    (33333, 'Unspecified', 3);

-- add a covering index to improve performance of the various options
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_TestData ON #TestData (EmployeeID, Amount DESC) INCLUDE (Category);

------------------------------------------

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Employee', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Employee;

CREATE TABLE #Employee (
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL
    );
INSERT #Employee (EmployeeID) VALUES
    (11111), (22222), (33333);

-- SELECT * FROM #TestData td;

--============================================================
--============================================================

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
    td.EmployeeID, td.Category, td.Amount
FROM
    #TestData td
ORDER BY 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY td.EmployeeID ORDER BY td.Amount DESC);

--============================================================

SELECT 
    tdt.EmployeeID, tdt.Category, tdt.Amount
FROM
    #Employee e
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            td.EmployeeID, td.Category, td.Amount
        FROM 
            #TestData td
        WHERE 
            e.EmployeeID = td.EmployeeID
        ORDER BY
            td.Amount DESC
        ) tdt;

--============================================================

WITH
    cte_AddRN AS (
        SELECT 
            td.EmployeeID, td.Category, td.Amount,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY td.EmployeeID ORDER BY td.Amount DESC)
        FROM
            #TestData td
        )
SELECT 
    ar.EmployeeID, ar.Category, ar.Amount
FROM
    cte_AddRN ar
WHERE 
    ar.RN = 1;
```

All 3 produce the same results...

```
EmployeeID  Category             Amount
----------- -------------------- ---------------------
11111       Vacation             4.00
22222       Personal             3.00
33333       Personal             5.00

EmployeeID  Category             Amount
----------- -------------------- ---------------------
11111       Vacation             4.00
22222       Personal             3.00
33333       Personal             5.00

EmployeeID  Category             Amount
----------- -------------------- ---------------------
11111       Vacation             4.00
22222       Personal             3.00
33333       Personal             5.00
```

Comment: That's the one that I'd have expected to be the winner but I've been surprised before. I'm glad you got it working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS`:

```
select *
from Employees
where not exists
  (select * from Employees as E
   where E.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID -- join condition
     and E.Amount>Employees.Amount) -- filter condition
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Category, Amount
FROM (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID 
      ORDER BY EmployeeID as rn ,Amount desc)
FROM getmaxdata) x WHERE x.rn =1
```